# Convert each Li element into an object

Tags: javascript, object, html-lists

I have an unordered list of players for a game that is dynamically generated by the user on the page. What I want to do is turn each list item into an object that will allow me to store their name and points. Struggling with the code as I am still learning JS. I have got as far as the function to create each object but I don't know how to actual create an object for John, Paul, Ringo and George (or whoever else the user may add to the list)

```
<ul id="playerList">
     <li>John</li>
     <li>Paul</li>
     <li>Ringo</li>
     <li>George</li>
</ul>  

const createPlayer = (playerName, points) => {return {name, points}}
```

Comment: Are the points in the html too? Or you want to set them yourself in the object?

Comment: It did - thank you very much for your input. I apologise as I thought I had already written a thank you comment but I see it did not post. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would get each of those `li` contents from your html and then do whatever you want to do with those datas :

```
var numberOfPlayers = getElementsByTagName('li').length;
for (i=0 ; i< numberOfPlayers; i++) {
var playerData document.getElementById('playerList').getElementsByTagName('li')[i].innerText;
// create your objects or do whatever you want with playerData
}
```

Based on Yishmeray suggestion you could also do it like that, among your preferences:

```
var playerData = document.querySelectorAll('#playerList li'); 
playerData.forEach(element => { 
var thisPlayerTxt = element.innerText;
//create your objects or do whatever you want with playerData
});
```

And just in case you would like to create a `li` and append it to your list:

```
var list = document.getElementById('playerList');
var name = 'John';
var player = document.createElement('li');
player.innerText = name;
list.appendChild(player);
```

Comment: May I suggest you explore a  -- var playerData = document.querySelectorAll('#playerList li');    playerData.forEach(el => { var thisPlayerTxt = el.innerText; }) -- and continuing as you already did above, which works just fine!